# how to fix SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing column [offer_profile_id] in table [offer]

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jhipster

I'm new to Jhipster and I am trying to create a one-to-one relationship between an already existing entity with a new entity, where the already existing entity will be the owning side

To this end I create a new entity that will be the owned side. The following are the steps I have followed

```
jhipster entity OfferProfile
Do you want to add a field to your entity? y

================= OfferProfile =================
Fields
sector (String) 
occupation (String) 

Generating relationships to other entities
? Do you want to add a relationship to another entity? (Y/n) Y
? What is the name of the other entity? Offer
? What is the name of the relationship? (offer) 
? What is the type of the relationship? 
  one-to-many 
  many-to-one 
  many-to-many 
❯ one-to-one 
? Is this entity the owner of the relationship? (y/N) N
? What is the name of this relationship in the other entity? (offerProfile)

? Do you want to use separate service class for your business logic? 
  No, the REST controller should use the repository directly 
  Yes, generate a separate service class 
❯ Yes, generate a separate service interface and implementation 
? Do you want to use a Data Transfer Object (DTO)? 
  No, use the entity directly 
❯ Yes, generate a DTO with MapStruct 
? Do you want to add filtering? 
  Not needed 
❯ Dynamic filtering for the entities with JPA Static metamodel 
? Do you want pagination on your entity? 
  No 
❯ Yes, with pagination links 
  Yes, with infinite scroll 

? Overwrite src/main/resources/config/liquibase/master.xml? overwrite
```

Then I added a new relationship to the existing entity

```
jhipster entity Offer
Found the .jhipster/Offer.json configuration file, entity can be automatically generated!

? Do you want to update the entity?
  Yes, re generate the entity 
❯ Yes, add more fields and relationships 
  Yes, remove fields and relationships 
  No, exit
  
? Do you want to add a field to your entity? (Y/n) n
? Do you want to add a relationship to another entity? (Y/n) Y
? What is the name of the other entity? OfferProfile
? What is the name of the relationship? (offerProfile)
? What is the type of the relationship? 
  one-to-many 
  many-to-one 
  many-to-many 
❯ one-to-one 
? Is this entity the owner of the relationship? (y/N) Y
? Do you want to use JPA Derived Identifier - @MapsId? (y/N)
? What is the name of this relationship in the other entity? (offer)
? When you display this relationship on client-side, which field from 'OfferProfile' do you want to use? ...
? Do you want to add any validation rules to this relationship? (y/N)
? Do you want to add a relationship to another entity? (Y/n) n

Generating relationships to other entities

? Do you want to add a relationship to another entity? No

================= Offer =================
Fields
...
Relationships
...

offerProfile (OfferProfile) one-to-one
conflict .jhipster/Offer.json
? Overwrite .jhipster/Offer.json? overwrite
    force .jhipster/Offer.json
 conflict src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/34234234_added_entity_Offer.xml
? Overwrite src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/2342343_added_entity_Offer.xml? overwrite
    force src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/78788_added_entity_Offer.xml
 conflict src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/787877_added_entity_constraints_Offer.xml
? Overwrite src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/45455_added_entity_constraints_Offer.xml? overwrite
    force src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/20190325191145_added_entity_constraints_Offer.xml
 conflict src/main/java/com/xpertopolis/offer/domain/Offer.java
? Overwrite src/main/java/com/xpertopolis/offer/domain/Offer.java? overwrite
    force src/main/java/com/xpertopolis/offer/domain/Offer.java
 conflict src/main/java/com/xpertopolis/offer/repository/OfferRepository.java
? Overwrite src/main/java/com/xpertopolis/offer/repository/OfferRepository.java? overwrite
    force src/main/java/com/xpertopolis/offer/repository/OfferRepository.java
 conflict src/main/java/com/xpertopolis/offer/web/rest/OfferResource.java
? Overwrite src/main/java/com/xpertopolis/offer/web/rest/OfferResource.java? overwrite
    force src/main/java/com/xpertopolis/offer/web/rest/OfferResource.java
 conflict src/main/java/com/xpertopolis/offer/service/dto/OfferCriteria.java
? Overwrite src/main/java/com/xpertopolis/offer/service/dto/OfferCriteria.java? overwrite
    force src/main/java/com/xpertopolis/offer/service/dto/OfferCriteria.java
 conflict src/main/java/com/xpertopolis/offer/service/OfferQueryService.java
? Overwrite src/main/java/com/xpertopolis/offer/service/OfferQueryService.java? overwrite
    force src/main/java/com/xpertopolis/offer/service/OfferQueryService.java
 conflict src/main/java/com/xpertopolis/offer/service/OfferService.java
? Overwrite src/main/java/com/xpertopolis/offer/service/OfferService.java? overwrite
    force src/main/java/com/xpertopolis/offer/service/OfferService.java
 conflict src/main/java/com/xpertopolis/offer/service/impl/OfferServiceImpl.java
? Overwrite src/main/java/com/xpertopolis/offer/service/impl/OfferServiceImpl.java? overwrite
    force src/main/java/com/xpertopolis/offer/service/impl/OfferServiceImpl.java
 conflict src/main/java/com/xpertopolis/offer/service/dto/OfferDTO.java
? Overwrite src/main/java/com/xpertopolis/offer/service/dto/OfferDTO.java? overwrite
    force src/main/java/com/xpertopolis/offer/service/dto/OfferDTO.java
identical src/main/java/com/xpertopolis/offer/service/mapper/EntityMapper.java
 conflict src/main/java/com/xpertopolis/offer/service/mapper/OfferMapper.java
? Overwrite src/main/java/com/xpertopolis/offer/service/mapper/OfferMapper.java? overwrite
    force src/main/java/com/xpertopolis/offer/service/mapper/OfferMapper.java
 conflict src/test/java/com/xpertopolis/offer/web/rest/OfferResourceIntTest.java
? Overwrite src/test/java/com/xpertopolis/offer/web/rest/OfferResourceIntTest.java? overwrite
    force src/test/java/com/xpertopolis/offer/web/rest/OfferResourceIntTest.java
identical src/main/resources/config/liquibase/master.xml
identical src/main/java/com/xpertopolis/offer/domain/enumeration/QASelectionStrategy.java
identical src/main/java/com/xpertopolis/offer/domain/enumeration/OfferStatus.java
```

In the offer entity this is the definition of the relationship that has been created

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(unique = true)
private OfferProfile offerProfile;
```

In the offer profile entity this is the definition of the relationship that has been created

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "offerProfile")
@JsonIgnore
private Offer offer;
```

When testing I get this error message

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing column [offer_profile_id] in table [offer]
```

I try to explicitly define the name of the field

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "offer_profile_id", referencedColumnName = "id", unique = true)
private OfferProfile offerProfile;
```

When try testing again I get the same error message

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing column [offer_profile_id] in table [offer]
```

How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you reviewed the generated Liquibase migrations? JHipster 7? Did you use incremental changelogs? Have you considered using JDL rather than questions?

Comment: Thanks for answering. In the process of regenerating the Offer entity, I am not overwriting the `liquibase` related thing, for example when asked about overwriting the file `src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/2342343_added_entity_Offer.xml?` I have answered no. Now, when repeating the process and answer Yes, I notice that the offer_profile_id field is indeed created.

`<column name = "offer_profile_id" type = "bigint">
<constraints unique = "true" nullable = "true" uniqueConstraintName = "ux_offer_offer_profile_id" />
</column>`

Comment: But now when testing I get the following error

`Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Referential integrity constraint violation: "FK_BID_OFFER_ID: PUBLIC.BID FOREIGN KEY(OFFER_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.OFFER(ID)"; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.bid ADD CONSTRAINT fk_bid_offer_id FOREIGN KEY (offer_id) REFERENCES PUBLIC.offer (id) [23506-197]`

Bid is another entity related with Offer.

I am new to this and again I appreciate your suggestions

Comment: It's just that your existing data violate the foreign key contraint you just added. So either your constraint is wrong and you must change it, or your constraint is valid and you must change existing data (in your database or in CSV files), nothing specific here, it's pure data modeling

Comment: A little further down the error message reads the following. `Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Constraint "FK_BID_OFFER_ID" already exists;` 

With this new information. Any ideas how to solve this?